# How to run FS2 streams when no Sync instance available?

Tags: scala, fs2

If I end up with an e.g. `Stream[Id, A]`, I can `translate` the effect `Pure` with the trivial `Id ~> Pure`.

However, if I've ended up with a stream of a different strict effect type, e.g. `Stream[Option, A]`, how can I convert this to a `Option[Vector[A]]` (or something)? The best way I've found so far is to translate the stream into some other type that *does* have a `Sync` instance, run the stream, but then it's not straightforward to convert it back as `Sync` admits all `Throwable`s as failures whereas `Option` naturally allows only `None`. What's the better way of approaching this?

Comment: How did you get a `Stream[Option, A]` in the first place?

Comment: Hah, I'm not defending it as a useful type. I had a `org.http4s.HttpService[F]` that I instantiated with `F = Option` and the bodies of the responses are then `Stream[Option, Byte]`.